# Can't put my new music I bought on my iTunes

Tags: itunes

My new iTunes music I have bought on my iPad isnt showing up on the iTunes on my computer so I can put it on my iPod help!

Answer (score 1):

The most likely problem is that your computer isn't logged in to the same AppleID as the one you purchased the music under. Go to System Preferences→iCloud and check which account you're logged in as. Alternatively, in iTunes look in the Store menu. One of the menu items will be "View Account (your_account_name_here)". If the account is correct, from the same menu select "Check for Available Downloads".